# Azure: create O365 events from MySQL database

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I want to create Office 365 calendar events which are in a MySQL table (on-premise server).

Currently, I'm planning to do it with Azure Data Factory and a Functions App.
I copying the MySQL Data from MySQL table to Azure Table Storage (this is working great).

After that, I want to create the event entries via Azure Function (HTTP Trigger, Looping all storage entities and creating calendar event via Graph API) but there are over 10,000 events in that table. The function would probably run too long.

Is there a better way to create these events? O365 can only be used as a source in Azure Data Factory. Maybe a batch in Azure Data Factory is better than a function? Should I run the Function, not for all events? For every single event (table insert trigger)? Are there other/better options to do that in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already writing to table storage then make a [Table Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table) and process one record at a time. So then all your 10000 event will be processed in multiple threads. But then you probably will need to think about write limits to calendar.

Comment: Ok sounds good. Are there limits to the calendar? The 10000 events are for different users. Not for one user.

Comment: @Shmukko I can't find limits but looks like they should be returned as part of the headers https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/

Comment: The limit is 10,000 requests per user, per app within a 10-minute window. For simplicity's sake, I generally define this in my code as "1,000 per minute". This is a little easier to wrap your head around. Technically a bit less than the actual limit (i.e. you could make 9,000 calls in the first minute and 1,000 calls in the 5th) but frankly, the practical challenges of optimizing for 10k/10 are generally not worth it and often require more scale on your app side than it's worth.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur where did you find that ?  or learn a hard way ?:)

Comment: It's a combination of hitting this issue myself a few years ago, pestering the author of that blog post you mentioned, and being up to my eyeballs in Graph for half a decade or so. So yes, the hard way. ;)